# Writing a function to calculate number of elemets in a c ctruct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Hi i am writing a program to calculate the number of elements currently in a struct but i have the following error and am not sure how to fix them, thanks in advance

I have these errors:

```
structponters.c:4:30: error: array type has incomplete element type
 void sizeStruct(struct point coordinates[]);
                          ^
structponters.c:4:24: warning: ‘struct point’ declared inside parameter list
 void sizeStruct(struct point coordinates[]);
                    ^
structponters.c:4:24: warning: its scope is only this definition or  

declaration, which is probably not what you want
structponters.c: In function ‘main’:

structponters.c:23:19: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
 sizeCoordinates = sizeof coordinates / sizeof coordinates[0];
               ^
structponters.c:28:14: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
 sizeStruct(coordinates);
          ^
structponters.c: In function ‘sizeStruct’:
structponters.c:35:26: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
  while(coordinates[i].x != NULL)
                      ^
structponters.c:28: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sizeStruct(struct point coordinates[]);

struct point{
  int x;
  int y;
};

main(){

  struct point *pp = malloc(sizeof(struct point));
  pp->x = 4;
  pp->y = 7;


  struct point coordinates[] = {{3,5}, {7,9}, {9,12}, {15, 19}};


  int *sizeCoordinates = malloc(sizeof(int));

  sizeCoordinates = sizeof coordinates / sizeof coordinates[0];
  printf("%d, %d\n", pp->x, pp->y);

  printf("size of coordinates is %d \n", sizeCoordinates);

  sizeStruct(coordinates);


}

void sizeStruct(struct point coordinates[]){
  int i =0;
  while(coordinates[i].x != NULL)
    i = i +1;
  printf("number of elemets in coordinates is: %d\n", i);

}
```

Comment: First few errors because you have `void sizeStruct(struct point coordinates[]);` before the `struct point` definition. Move the former down a few lines to be after `struct point`.

Comment: `sizeCoordinates = sizeof coordinates / sizeof coordinates[0];` --> `*sizeCoordinates = sizeof coordinates / sizeof coordinates[0];` and `printf("size of coordinates is %d \n", sizeCoordinates);` --> `printf("size of coordinates is %d \n", *sizeCoordinates);` and you can't count the number of elements without passing the length as a parameter to `sizeStruct`. Here : `while(coordinates[i].x != NULL)`, `coordinates[i].x` is an `int` while `NULL` is a pointer.

Comment: And it seems the question has been answered in the comments. Please add an actual answer!!!!!!!!!! Answering in comments is causing a lot of discussion on meta.

Comment: thanks that's what the problem was, This function calculates the number of coordinates in the array: 

    void sizeStruct(struct point coordinates[]){
    int i =0;
  int num_elements = 0;
  while(coordinates[i].x != NULL)
    i = i +1;

  num_elements = i;

  printf("number of elemets in coordinates is: %d\n", num_elements);


}

Comment: As it stands both variations of `sizeStruct()` invoke undefined behaviour by reading (at least) one past the array's boundaries. Not good.

Comment: To explicitly state this: **It is not possible in C** to derive the size of an array via a pointer to the array's 1st element only (as you try in `sizeStruct()`).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Required before `sizeStruct` because sizeStruct use the `struct point`
struct point{
    int x;
    int y;
};

void sizeStruct(struct point coordinates[]);

int main(void){
    struct point *pp = malloc(sizeof(struct point));
    pp->x = 4;
    pp->y = 7;

    struct point coordinates[] = {{3,5}, {7,9}, {9,12}, {15, 19}, { 0, 0}};//{0,0} is sentinel

    int sizeCoordinates;//no need malloc, just use int

    sizeCoordinates = sizeof coordinates / sizeof coordinates[0];

    printf("%d, %d\n", pp->x, pp->y);

    printf("size of coordinates is %d \n", sizeCoordinates);

    sizeStruct(coordinates);

    free(pp);

    return 0;
}

void sizeStruct(struct point coordinates[]){
    int i =0;
    while(coordinates[i].x != 0 && coordinates[i].y != 0)//!= NULL : Comparison of the int and pointer type incorrect
        i = i + 1;
    printf("number of elemets in coordinates is: %d\n", i);//The number of valid data
}
```